# Material-UI components not found during TypeScript module resolution

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 (v16.3.2) React TypeScript project which includes the Material-UI components. The TypeScript compiler can not resolve any of the @material-ui imports and errors such as the following occur causing the corresponding JavaScript not to be generated.

```
Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module '@material-ui/core/Grid'.
```

The module for the error above is

```
import * as React from 'react';

// Material-UI
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

// Components
import SkiWeekends from './SkiWeekends';

const EZForm: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <SkiWeekends/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          A
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          B
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          A
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default EZForm;
```

The tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "es6"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The package.json is

```
{
  "name": "msc",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "12.7.9",
    "@types/react": "16.9.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.0",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "2.1.32",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.5.0",
    "react": "16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "16.10.1",
    "react-redux": "7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have verified the @material-ui packages are installed in the node_modules folder.

[image]

All other packages/imports work correctly. Thoughts on why the material-ui modules are not being resolved during TS compilation appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem and my fix was to add  `"moduleResolution": "node"` to tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 8):

For me the problem was fixed by simply removing all the import declarations and adding them again.

Comment: Too weird.. but this also worked for me. Suspect something else was going on, but ??

Comment: I think the reason behind it could be this, Typescript caches all of your import statements if none of the import statements have changed, but if something has changed for example removing and adding your import statements, then TS server might check for the type definitions again.

Comment: I had to restart vscode and that did it

Answer (score 4):

After some research it turns out the tsconfig include section needs to be modified from the default value to find files in subdirectories.

Default include only finds files in the src folder

```
"include": [
  "src"
]
```

modified finds files in any subdirectory

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*"
]
```

Good reference on tsconfig.json

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I find this odd as the `node_modules` folder is not included within `src`. I'm having the same problem but so far no solution.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem solved by running `npm install` / `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by running `yarn add @material-ui/data-grid`
And I don't see the `@material-ui/data-grid` package in your package.json so I think that is missing

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by importing @mui/material. The name was changed some time back.